# np.unique() explanation?

Tags: numpy

What happends in this numpy function:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 5, 3, 2])
u, indices = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
```

The results are:

```
u
```

array([1, 2, 3, 5)]

```
indices
```

array([0,1,3,2,1), dtype=int64)

```
u[indices]
```

array([1, 2, 5, 3, 1])

u are the single values inside this array. What is indices? why is it a 3 and not a 5? and what is going on in u[indices]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the function returns the variables `u` and `indices`:

- `u` contains the unique elements sorted. In other words no element is repeated (the number 2 does not appear twice) and the elements will be listed from the smallest to the largest value
- `indices` is the same size as `a` and basically it contains the index in `u` you should used to recover `a`. So when they give you [0,1,3,2,1], in this case the number 3 refers to the 3rd index of `u` = [1, 2, 3, 5] which in this case is 5

You can see how `u` and `indices` can be used to recover `a` by running the following code:

```
for element in indices:
      print(u[element])
```

This also explains your last question: `u[indices]` it basically gives you back `a`. Note that in your question `u[indices]` should return array([1, 2, 5, 3, 2]). I assume you made a typo